# Adding <li> to an <ul> based on categories in a select list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, html-lists

I have a bunch of `<ul>` on a page with `<h2>` just above each one that is a category name. I am going to use `PHP` to populate the select list with each category name as an `<option>`, but what I need to know how to do is add a new `<li>` to each list based on the category name. How can I accomplish this using jQuery? I don't have any starter code.

EDIT: Allow me to clarify. I have something like this:

```
<form action="addSomething.php" method="post">
    <select name="categories">
        <option value="0">Pick one</option>
        <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
        <option value="2">Cat 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="title" />
    <input type="text" id="URL" />
    <input type="submit" id="addNew">
</form>

<h2>Cat 1</h2>
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to use the form above to select a category (the `<h2>`), enter a name & URL, and then add it as a new `<li>` that corresponds to the selected category.

Comment: Will be hard to help without any starter code

Comment: You're talking about 2 different things here. A <ul> has <li> elements, but a <select> is a dropdown element that's populated with <option> elements. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I know. I am trying to add <li> to an <ul> based off the names in a <select> list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select each `ul`, get it's category, append an `li`.

html

```
<h2 class="category">cat1</h2>
<ul></ul>
<h2 class="category">cat2</h2>
<ul></ul>
<h2 class="category">cat3</h2>
<ul></ul>
```

js

```
$("ul").each(function(){
    var category = this.prev("h2").text();
    $("<li>" + category + "</li>").appendTo(this);
});
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7jz/). Of course you can put whatever text you want inside those `lis` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Without starter code, very hard to help. Here's the general idea:

```
<h2>Sample List</h2>
<ul class="someClass"></ul>

<select>
    <option value="someval">some option</option>
    <option value="someval2">some option</option>
</select>
```

And your JS can be:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "someval") {
        $("ul .someClass").append("<li>" + this.value + "</li>");
    }
});
```

Without any starter code, it's difficult to the exact solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what your after, but this may help:

```
$('h2.categoryName').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).text();
    $(this).next('ul').append('<li>' + name + '</li>');
});
```